# Regex for matching a pattern with one length or another

Tags: regex

I need to match a pattern with strictly 10-symbols length OR 12 (not 11). So this won't work

```
[0-9]{10,12}
```

Can I write something more simple than

```
([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{12})
```

?

Comment: Please specify the language/regex flavour you use. Different flavours make different things possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?` to set a char or group as optional :

```
\d{10}(\d\d)?
```

Don't forget to match start and end if that's the whole regex :

```
^\d{10}(\d\d)?$
```

Comment: This is correct for this regex, but the pattern can be more complicated than just numbers

Comment: Then use the more complicated pattern, the important point is the ? to make an optionnal group.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work..

```
(pattern)((\1){11}|((\1){9}))
```

I've just used backreference in php (\1)....